# ¿Cómo crear un navbar estático en Bootstrap y visualizar en él un menú de grandes proporciones correctamente?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, navbar

Tengo un nabvar en Bootstrap que funciona perfecto en todas las vistas menos en la vista móvil horizontal. Al presionar sobre el dropwdown, se abre el desplegable y al tener bastantes elementos uno debajo del otro, este no entra en toda la pantalla y queda casi todo el menú desplegable sin poder visionarse y sin posibilidad de hacer scroll.

Este es el código del nabvar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-static fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
            <img src="images/logo2.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Inicio
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Alquiler
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=altavoces"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Altavoces</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=amplificadores"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Amplificadores</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=equipo-dj"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Equipo DJ</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=efectos"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Efectos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=mesas-de-directo"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Mesas de Directo</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=microfonos"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Micrófonos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=procesadores"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Procesadores</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=iluminacion"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Iluminación</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=proyectores"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Proyectores</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=tv-plasmas"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Tv Plasmas</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=tarimas"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Tarimas</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquileres.php?categoria=complementos"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Complementos</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Servicios
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="discomovil.php"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Discomovil</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="videoconferencias.php"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Videoconferencias y Streaming</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquiler-televisores-valencia.php"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Alquiler de televisores</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="discomovil-bodas.php"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Discomovil para bodas</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="alquiler-pantalla-proyector.php"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>Pantallas y proyectores</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="galeria.php">Galería</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contacto.php">Contacto</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Como veis el primer dropdown tiene bastantes elementos y en el segundo acabará pasando lo mismo. No sé si hay soluciones para esto y de haberlas cual sería las más eficiente.

Comment: Buenas, para poder ayudarte, debes realizar un [mre] de tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

### Solución para navbar estático

En este caso será necesario utilizar una línea CSS debido a que en Bootstrap no existe aun la clase especifica que necesitamos que sería `vh-md-100`.

También en este caso puedes prescindir de la clase `navbar-static` del `<nav>` y obviamente deberás mantener la clase `fixed-top`.

1. Al elemento div de la clase `collapse` añadir la clase `vh-100` la cual le dará al nav desplegado un tamaño equivalente a la altura de la pantalla.
2. Será necesario añadir también la clase `overflow-auto` a este mismo elemento, la cual se encargará de que aparezca el scroll que permitirá de moverse a través de las opciones del nav una vez desplegado.

*Ejemplo:*

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse vh-100 overflow-auto" id="navbarResponsive">
```

Si nos limitamos a hacer solo esto tendremos un problema, ya que el navbar en su versión de escritorio se encuentra expandido y de consecuencia ocuparía el 100% de la página impidiendo que esta pueda ser utilizada. Para resolver este inconveniente será necesario añadir la siguiente línea de CSS la cual hace que la altura del nav sea automática en la versión de escritorio:

```
@media(min-width:992px){.navbar-collapse{height:auto !important}}
```

> Nota: No puedes prescindir de especificar la altura del `navbar-collapse` porque la clase `fixed-top` impide visualizar el `<nav>` cuando este excede el tamaño de la página. Hacer scroll será posible solo cuando los elementos del menú excedan el tamaño especificado al `navbar-collapse` que los contiene.

---

### Solución para navbar no estático

1. Asegúrate de que la navbar se encuentra dentro de la etiqueta `<body>` fuera de cualquier contenedor.
2. Elimina del `<nav>` las clases `fixed-top` que es la causa de que no se active el scroll en la página.
3. En este caso tampoco será necesario el uso de la clase `navbar-static`.

*Debería quedar así:*

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```